# How to apply Abel's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, power-series

[image]
In this example, where does the term $log(1+x)$ come from? And can someone briefly summarize the steps we take when we want to apply Abel's theorem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The power series for $\;\log(1+x)\;,\;\;|x|<1\;$ is precisely the one you have there:

$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n$$

and since the numeric function $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n\;$ of the series converges (it is a Leibniz series), Abel's theorem tells us that

$$\log(1+1)=\log 2=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n$$

Answer (score 2):

The derivate of $f(x)=ln(1+x)$ is $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$. $g(x)$ has the taylor series

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^jx^j$$

This sum converges for $x<1$ and Abel's theorem shows that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}x^j}{j}$$ converges also for $x=1$ and that the value of the sum is $f(1)=ln(2)$